# go run: cannot run non-main package

Tags: go, google-app-engine-go

here the simple go application. I am getting "go run: cannot run non-main package" error, if I run following code.

```
package zsdfsdf

import (
    "fmt"
)

func Main() {
    fmt.Println("sddddddd")
}
```

To fix it, I just need to name the package to `main`. But I don't understand why I need to do that. I should be able to name the package whatever I want.

Another question, I know main function is the entry point of the program, you need it. otherwise it will not work. But I see some codes that didn't have main function still works.

Click on this link, the example at the bottom of the page didn't use package main and main function, and it still works. just curious why.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/gettingstarted/usingdatastore

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to specify in your app.yaml file what your app access point is. Take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/gettingstarted/helloworld). You need to specify:

```
application: zsdfsdf
```

Also see from that above link:

> "Note: When writing a stand-alone Go program we would place this code
>   in package main. The Go App Engine Runtime provides a special main
>   package, so you should put HTTP handler code in a package of your
>   choice (in this case, hello)."

You are correct that all Go programs need the `Main` method. But it is provided by Google App Engine. That is why your provided example works. Your example would not work locally (not on GAE).

Answer (score 58):

The entry point of each go program is `main.main`, i.e. a function called main in a package called main. You have to provide such a main package.

GAE is an exception though. They add a `main` package, containing the `main` function automatically to your project. Therefore, you are not allowed to write your own.

Answer (score 38):

You need to use the **main package**, a common error starting with go is to type

```
package Main
```

instead of

```
package main
```

Answer (score 8):

A Solution to avoid this error is defining entry point `somefilename.go` file as main package by adding `package main` as the first line of the entry point

```
package main

// import statements 
import "fmt"

// code below
```

Answer (score 4):

To avoid the problem you can modify the code as follow

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
 )

func main() {
    fmt.Println("sddddddd")
 }
```

rename the package as "main" and rename the function as "main" instead of "Main".

Comment: The author knows how to fix it. His question is why he need to do that.

Comment: I am getting `main redeclared in this block` error on the`func main()` line, does anyone know why is this happening?