# Not able to create custom packages in golang

Tags: go

I am pretty new to GO. I was trying few examples and one of them was to use cgo to call a C code from GO.

Here is the example I am trying: https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/cgo

With the above link as a reference I created a package structure as below:

gocode/src/github.com/mypkg/test.go

"mypkg" is the custom package that I have created and used it in the test.go as below:

package mypkg

I get an error when I run my go program.
**"go run: cannot run non-main package"**

I have set my GOPATH to the GO source code folder.

GOPATH=/xyz/gocode/src/

I searched for solutions and found the below links which says, custom pacakages cannot be created:
    https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/vmebkoqYMH4

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870801/go-run-cannot-run-non-main-package
```

But, All the code I see is with a custom pacakage name. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Create dir `mypackage` and `mypackage.go` in `$GOPATH`

put in `mypackage.go` following code

```
package mypackage

func Hello() {
   println("hello")
}
```

Create `main.go`

```
package main

import "mypackage"

func main() {
     mypackage.Hello()
}
```

`go run` command must be applied to `main` package

**In you case, create main.go file and import `github.com/mypkg`**

Also importing packages should not contain `main` function.

Answer (score 2):

`go run` is for executables, and works on separate files. Use `go install` and `go build` to work with packages. Additional reading: http://golang.org/doc/code.html.

Answer (score 0):

I have been through this problem. It is showing this error because there is no main package in any .go file. You should create a main folder in which create a main.go file to call main package function main and import your package in that just like below:

```
package main 
import(
    "fmt"
    "github.com/mypkg"
)
func main(){
// use use your package functions here by packagename.functionname
    mypkg.functionName()
    fmt.Println("Hello")
}
```

Now build the package by moving to mypkg directory and run `go build` on terminal or command line if you are window user.
Move up to main directory which contains main.go file and run `go install`
it will create executable file in the name of main directory. The directory structure be like.

```
workspace
  ├── bin
  │   └── app
  ├── pkg
  │   └── linux_amd64
  |         └── user
  |              └── handlers.a
  └── src
    ├── bitbucket.org
    ├── github.com
         └── user
              └── app
                   ├── main.go
                   └── mypkg
                         └──mypkg.go
```